# MPAndroidChart fill color gradient

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

Is it possible with MPAndroidChart (or any other Android chart library) to fill the chart under the draw line with a gradient color? Something like this:

```
set1.setFillColor(getResources().getColor(R.drawable.chart_fill));
```

then in `chart_fill.xml`:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:endColor="#FF207a54"
        android:startColor="#FFffffff" />

</shape>
```

Comment: Any update on this? Did MPAndroidChart include the gradient fill color feature in any of the newer versions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay i have found a solution:

[William Chart](https://github.com/diogobernardino/WilliamChart) and i am using this method:

```
int[] colors = { getResources().getColor(R.color.menu_text),
 getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white) };

float[] index = { 0, 1 };
dataset.setGradientFill(colors, index);
```

Answer (score 47):

You can use the following two methods:

```
LineRadarDataSet#setDrawFilled(boolean isFilled); 
LineRadarDataSet#setFillDrawable(Drawable d);
```

Here's a link to the [javadoc](https://jitpack.io/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v3.0.1/javadoc/com/github/mikephil/charting/data/LineRadarDataSet.html) for that class.

This is the example from the <strike>[MPAndroidChart sample project](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/LineChartActivity1.java):</strike>

```
set1.setDrawFilled(true);
if (Utils.getSDKInt() >= 18) {
    // fill drawable only supported on api level 18 and above
    Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.fade_red);
    set1.setFillDrawable(drawable);
}
else {
    set1.setFillColor(Color.BLACK);
}
```

In `fade_red.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:startColor="#00ff0000"
        android:endColor="#ffff0000" />
</shape>
```

Here's a sample of what it looks like on a `LineChart`:

[image: a line chart with a red gradient fill]

Comment: How to fill, depend on positive or negative values, with different colors ?

Comment: You should also add set1.setDrawFilled(true); for the fill to show up. Hope this helps someone out there.

Comment: how to remove this dotted line?

Comment: This should be an accepted answer.

Answer (score 10):

**Kotlin Solution:**

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
    lineDataSet.setDrawFilled(true)
    val fillGradient = ContextCompat.getDrawable(requireContext(), R.drawable.red_gradient)
    lineDataSet.fillDrawable = fillGradient
}
```

Here is the `red_gradient.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:startColor="#00F81616"
        android:endColor="#ffF81616" />
</shape>
```