# MPCharts - Line Chart (gradient fill) is not working in API Level 16

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

im using line chart (MPCharts) gradient fill working perfectly with API Level 19 but not in API Level 16 (and bellow i guess). is it a bug or do i have to try in different manner?

Thanks.

I used These codes.

```
LineDataSet set1 = new LineDataSet(yVals, "Close");
Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplication(),R.drawable.gradiant);
                drawable.setAlpha(200);
                set1.setFillDrawable(drawable);
                set1.setDrawFilled(true);
```

Screen Shots,

[image: This is API level 16]

[image: This is API level 19]

Comment: Fill drawable only works with `minimum sdkVersion >= 18`.

Answer (score 1):

```
set1.setDrawFilled(true);
if (Utils.getSDKInt() >= 18) {
    // fill drawable only supported on api level 18 and above
    Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.gradiant);
    set1.setFillDrawable(drawable);
}
else {
    set1.setFillColor(Color.BLACK);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32907529/mpandroidchart-fill-color-gradient/61768716#61768716) is a `Kotlin` solution for filling `LineChart` line bottom side.