# Gradient color in graph bar using MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, kotlin

I would like to make a graph like this :

[image]

The problem is I don't know how to set a gradient color like this using MPAndroidChart. Maybe I should use an other library ?

Maybe it's better to use progressbar with transparent color (and gradient background) ?

This is my code :

```
val entries = ArrayList<BarEntry>()
    entries.add(BarEntry(1.toFloat(), 43.toFloat()))
    entries.add(BarEntry(2.toFloat(), 3.toFloat()))
    entries.add(BarEntry(3.toFloat(), 13.toFloat()))
    entries.add(BarEntry(4.toFloat(), 41.toFloat()))
    entries.add(BarEntry(5.toFloat(), 22.toFloat()))
    entries.add(BarEntry(6.toFloat(), 11.toFloat()))
    entries.add(BarEntry(7.toFloat(), 13.toFloat()))
    entries.add(BarEntry(8.toFloat(), 99.toFloat()))
    entries.add(BarEntry(9.toFloat(), 67.toFloat()))
    entries.add(BarEntry(10.toFloat(), 3.toFloat()))
    entries.add(BarEntry(11.toFloat(), 56.toFloat()))
    entries.add(BarEntry(12.toFloat(), 88.toFloat()))



    val dataSet = BarDataSet(entries, "Label")


    chart.data = BarData(dataSet)
```

Comment: share your code.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use `setGradientFill()` method which will accept n number of color.

```
int[] colors = { getResources().getColor(R.color.menu_text),
 getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white) };

float[] index = { 0, 1 };
dataset.setGradientFill(colors, index);
```

for more you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32942554/5110595). Hope it will help you!!

Comment: .setGradientFill is not a known method in v 3.1.0-alpha (latest as of today), so this solutions seems outdated. There are other methods; .setGradientColor() and .setGradientColors(), but these does not work (at least not on Horizontal Bar graph).

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
dataset.setGradientColor(Color.parseColor("#00FF5722"),Color.parseColor("#FFFF5722"));
```