# MPAndroidChart: use pattern fill for barchart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

We are using the MPAndroidChart library in our project.

We are drawing a stackedbar chart, and each bar gets a background color that is received from a service. For this we just use

```
int[] colors = new int[size];
for(....
{
   //set color value
}

BarDataSet set = new BarDataSet(.....;
set.setColors(colors);
```

Some bars however should be drawn with a hatch pattern. How can we achieve this ?

[image: example of a hatched bar]

Comment: Have you checked here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42194576/2910520 ?

Comment: @Knarf means you want to remove that Hatched lines from the bar, right?

Comment: No I want to add a hatch pattern to certain bars in my graph.
I checked that solution. But that does not work for BarChart.

Comment: @Knarf did you find a solution for this?